# Can I refrence an IIF value in a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a report in Excel that Queryies data from an ODBC table.

I wanted to create a new column for a search criteria, and use it in my where clause.
for example:

```
SELECT 
SO_Site,
SO_Customer,
IIF((SO_PERFORM_DATE)<GetDate(),'Backlog','Normal') AS 'ISBACKLOG'

FROM WAREHOUSE.FAKESALESORDES

WHERE SO_Site=1234 AND ISBACKLOG='Backlog'
```

The aim of this was to return backlog orders, without a super messy where clause, so others can interpret this query in the future.

Any tips would be very helpful!

Comment: IIF is an Excel (and Access)-specific thing AFAIK. In most SQL dialects you'd probably use a CASE statement instead. It might depend on what kind of database you're connecting to.

Comment: The short answer is - you can't. Logically the WHERE clause is applied before the computation of ISBACKLOG so that column doesn't exist. However, you know exactly which rows qualify for `ISBACKUP = 'Backlog'` so the easy approach is to move that logic into the where clause as `WHERE ... AND SO_PERFORM_DATE < GETDATE()`. And please use some whitespace and formatting to make your code more readable. You and anyone else you work with will appreciate that effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reference a named alias in its own `WHERE` like that.

You simply need to put the whole `IIF` in the `WHERE` statement the same as it is in the `SELECT`

```
SELECT 
    SO_Site,
    SO_Customer,
    IIF((SO_PERFORM_DATE)<GetDate(),'Backlog','Normal') AS 'ISBACKLOG'

FROM 
    WAREHOUSE.FAKESALESORDES

WHERE 
    SO_Site=1234 
    AND IIF((SO_PERFORM_DATE)<GetDate(),'Backlog','Normal')='Backlog'
```

Although looking at the conditions within the `IIF` you can simplify this even further by just looking where the date is less than `GETDATE()`

```
SELECT 
    SO_Site,
    SO_Customer,
    IIF((SO_PERFORM_DATE)<GetDate(),'Backlog','Normal') AS 'ISBACKLOG'

FROM 
    WAREHOUSE.FAKESALESORDES

WHERE 
    SO_Site=1234 
    AND SO_PERFORM_DATE<GetDate()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are, of course, ways around this. But you need to learn to walk before trying to run. This does not scratch the surface of complex or messy! But you can use a CTE in many cases to reduce the visual complexity or duplication. Example:

```
WITH ORDERS as (
    SELECT 
       SO_Site,
       SO_Customer,
       CASE WHEN SO_PERFORM_DATE < GetDate() THEN 'Backlog' 
            ELSE 'Normal' END ) AS ISBACKLOG
FROM WAREHOUSE.FAKESALESORDES 
)
select SO_Site, SO_Customer, ISBACKLOG
from ORDERS where ISBACKLOG = 'BackLog'
order by ...;
```

Demo as [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=614563902debb9a367f6245ee9cc46c0). You might also consider using a view or a [computed column](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=95aac9c5132d0ea270ca9f36e7854ef1)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `CASE` statement, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
  SO_Site,
  SO_Customer,
  CASE WHEN SO_PERFORM_DATE < GetDate() THEN 'Backlog' ELSE 'Normal' END AS 'ISBACKLOG'
  FROM WAREHOUSE.FAKESALESORDES
  WHERE SO_Site=1234
)  a
WHERE a.ISBACKLOG='Backlog';
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp).

Comment: Thank you. I am getting: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'ISBACKLOG'.  Could this be due to only having read access to the ODBC server?

Comment: IsBacklog column do not exist in the WHERE because the where is executed before the SELECT field

Comment: @Bestter Thank you, I forgot about that!